# Receiver срабатывает сразу после перезагрузки

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-alarm-manager

Receiver почему то срабатывает практически сразу (1-2 минуты) после перезагрузки, хотя в `AlarmManager` устанавливал совсем другое время(допустим через 20 минут или час).

вот часть манифеста:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Установка:

```
                    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePickerHours);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePickerMinutes);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    toWakeUpIntent = new Intent(context, WakeUp.class);
    toWakeUpIntent.putExtra("id", intent.getExtras().getInt("id"));
    toWakeUpIntent.putExtra("checkDays", intent.getExtras().getBooleanArray("checkDays"));
    toWakeUpIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(toWakeUpIntent);
    Log.e(TAG, "в Receiver");
}
```

Comment: в добавок: Активность как таковая на экране не появляется, которую вызывает `Receiver`, но срабатывает сервис внутри неё.

Comment: Возможно, у вас происходит срабатывание из-за того, что вы устанавливаете время меньше текущего

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нет, я ставлю и на час больше и на 2, всегда срабатывает сразу после перезагрузки

Comment: Что то я не очень понял. Вы подписаны на событие включения девайса , он у вас срабатывает, но вы не хотите, чтобы он срабатывал?...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я хочу, чтобы он срабатывал в определенное время, которое я указал в AlarmManager, он же срабатывает мгновенно после перезагрузки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас смешались две задачи в одну.

Вам надо отдельный ресивер для события загрузки девайса и отдельный, другой ресивер с другим `IntentFilter` для вашего аларма.

Т.е. вам надо:

1. создать ещё один класс-ресивер
2. прописать его в манифесте
3. убедиться, что он имеет тэг `<intent-filter>` с правильно прописанным именем события, т.е. таким же как у `PendingIntent`, коий вы создаёте для аларма
4. Убедиться, что `PendingIntent`, коий вы создаёте для аларма должен вызвать правильный ресивер, т.е. второй, новый.

Comment: можно поподробнее с `IntentFilter`? В первом ресивере понятно, что там `BOOT_COMPLETED`, а во втором что?
И правильно я понял, что без перезагрузки работает ресивер - алярм, при перезагрузке срабатывает другой ресивер, который вызывает ресивер - алярм?

Comment: Во втором должна быть строка, кою вы передаёте в метод setAction при создании интента для создания ПенджинИнтента, коий потом используется для создания аларма. У вас сейчас, вроде, в принципе никто не ловит событие аларма, а ресивер, ловящий событие запуска девайса исполняет код, который должен выполнятся ещё не существующим другим ресивером. Т.е. ваш нынешний ресивер вообще к задаче не относится

Comment: нынешний ресивер у меня срабатывает, если телефон не перезагружать. Но как я понял, перезагрузка и НЕперезагрузка - это 2 разных события, которые должны по разному обрабатываться?

Comment: @Ivan если после перезагрузки Аларм не срабатывает, то в ресивере перезагрузки заново создайте аларм. Значения нужные можно в префересы/БД записать

Comment: у меня такой вопрос. Я устанавливаю в случайном классе алярм и интенту явно указываю второй ресивер(без интент-фильтра и BOOT_COMPLETED в манифесте), в первом ресивере устанавливаю BOOT_COMPLETED и алярм. И вроде бы всё работает, т.е. без перезагрузки ловится второй ресивер, который я явно указал, при перезагрузке ловится первый, хотя явно я его не указывал. Нет ли в этом каких нибудь подводных камней?

Comment: @Ivan, для ресивера загрузки вы явно указали на что он должен реагировать в манифесте - т.е. прописали ему в интент-фильтре, что он должен на событие загрузки реагировать. А подводные камни... Они где-нибудь точно есть. Вроде слышал, что не все девайсы нормально рассылают это самое событие завершения загрузки. Точнее - некоторые девайсы перезагружаются по своему и это событие просто не вызывается.

Comment: вы про HTC? В гугле нашел, что `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />`, `<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />` и  `<action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />` вроде как решают эту проблему, но проверить не могу. А вообще большое спасибо.

Comment: @Ivan, да, про них) Вообще, проблемы почти всегда и везде возникают - всего не предусмотришь)

Comment: у меня сходу вопрос возник, вы говорите, что из-за `BOOT_COMPLETED` мой ресивер получает событие на загрузку. А какой интент он получает, если я явно указываю на другой ресивер?

Comment: @Ivan, не понял вопроса. В общем случае ресивер срабатывает на тот интент, который прописан в его интент-фильтре